# Bindable boolean in array that's togglable SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array in SwiftUI where it's an array of a struct that contains a boolean value which is bounded by a Toggle.

```swift
struct Blah {
    @State var enabled = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State public var blahs: [Blah] = [
        Blah(false)
   ]

   var body : some View {
      List(blahs) { blah in
           Toggle(isOn: blah.$enabled)
      }
   }
}
```

the `blahs` arrays will have a button that will append more `Blah` objects. Xcode is telling me this though:

`Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.`

How should I change this? I don't think I'm applying the concept right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@State should only be used on a View — it shouldn’t be used inside your model.

Once you’ve removed that, you can use the [element binding syntax](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/) to get bindings to individual items on the List:

```
struct Blah : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var enabled = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State public var blahs: [Blah] = [
        Blah(false)
   ]

   var body : some View {
      List($blahs) { $blah in
           Toggle(isOn: $blah.enabled)
      }
   }
}
```